# How can i validate password for user login

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-membership

I have the following code to check for valid users:

```
protected void Login_LoginError(object sender, EventArgs e) {
    //See if this user exists in the database 

    MembershipUser userinfo = Membership.GetUser(Login.UserName);

    if (userinfo == null || !userinfo.IsApproved || userinfo.IsLockedOut) {
        //The user entered an invalid username/password...
        Login.FailureText = "Invalid User/Password";
    } else {
        Login.FailureText = string.Empty;
    }
}
```

This code doesn't show the failure text when the password is wrong for users, I need code-behind logic for validating both the user and password! Any suggestions appreciated.

Comment: The simple answer to this is to create your own Membership Provider.  You are too "late" in the validation execution.

Comment: but I can check user name from db ... it should be another way to check them both .. but i don't know if I can show failure text from own Membership . could u give links for that !

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should use the Authenticate handler on the login control.  For more reading see [this link](http://www.c-sharpcorner.com/uploadfile/raj1979/login-control-in-Asp-Net-3-5/)

If you're using the out of the box MembershipProvider you can authenticate your user with the [Membership.ValidateUser method](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.security.membership.validateuser.aspx) in the Authenticate handler.

Comment: If you're using a MembershipProvider you don't even need to handle the Authenticate handler of the login control, it's implicit that it will use the defaultProvider as specified in your membership configuration - http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms731049.aspx

Comment: Yes, but the OP seemed to indicate that the default functionality was not validating correctly, so it seemed likely that this info would be useful, if only to help figure out why its not working as expected.